# Issues with the Discord API: Unknown interaction discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Whenever I run a command for this example, the `/ping` command which should normally return the bot's latency, is now just stuck at displaying " is thinking..." and doesn't seem to return anything.

I have already tried updating all packages but it didn't seem to work. I'm not really sure if this is an issue in my actual code or if it's an API issue with Discord.

I have logged all uncaught errors and got this:

```
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM   [Anti-Crash] :: Unhandled Rejection/Catch
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM  DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM      at RequestHandler.execute (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM      at async RequestHandler.push (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM      at async CommandInteraction.deferReply (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:61:5)
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM      at async Object.execute (/opt/render/project/src/Commands/ping.js:11:5) {
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM    method: 'post',
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM    path: '/interactions/1171862223220654120/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTE3MTg2MjIyMzIyMDY1NDEyMDp0U1g1c0UwcWo4ZUhndVdoUTlXRlYzTmp2UjBtRjRFOFZtOUFwNndaRHlEWTBXNjJYQ1RvUWlJdjVpRkp3TDA1NmJtcVRHeVNZZ2s3UVoxMWF0ZWU1cVk2Rkk4a3BKY0E0VWtWd21uREMxQkJwOTdLeWRtZlhoNzlXakRyMDk0Yg/callback',
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM    code: 10062,
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM    httpStatus: 404,
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM    requestData: { json: { type: 5, data: [Object] }, files: [] }
Nov 8 06:22:06 PM  }
```

Here is my `/ping` command code that causes this error:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('Replies with pong!'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.deferReply({ephemeral: true});
    await interaction.editReply({ content: `Pong! 
    ${interaction.client.ws.ping} ms`, ephemeral: true ,});
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An "unknown interaction" is common when you attempt to work with any interaction that no longer exists, this is due to the fact that Discord invalidates any interaction if the bot does not acknowledge the interaction within 3 seconds.

From Discord.js documentation on [deferred responses](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#deferred-responses):

> Discord requires an acknowledgement from your bot within three seconds that the interaction was received. Otherwise, Discord considers the interaction to have failed and the token becomes invalid.

In your case, your `async` function is running both `deferReply` and `editReply` and it is possible that one is being triggered after the other, or taking too long in its current context which causes the interaction to timeout.

Your `deferReply` seems unecessary in this case since you are responding to the interaction with `editReply` so removing the deferral should resolve this. If you still continue to experience this error, it may be helpful to investigate how long your interaction calls are actually taking to respond and whether or not they are being handled within a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to update this, but the code started working again magically. It seems like it was actually an issue with discord, and not with my code. I have checked the discord status page and it looks like discord indeed was having some issues with it's API at the time of me creating this question.